# Calling DialogFragment in Fragment Kotlin

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I'm trying to call my dialogfragment into my loginfragment and show an alert dialog box, the show method says that:

> None of the following functions can be called with the arguments
>   supplied. show(FragmentManager!, String!) defined in
>   org.greenstand.android.TreeTracker.fragments.CustomDialogFragment
>   show(FragmentTransaction!, String!) defined in
>   org.greenstand.android.TreeTracker.fragments.CustomDialogFragment

```
val newFragment = CustomDialogFragment.newInstance("pass content here")

val fm = fragmentManager
newFragment.show(fm, "look")
```

Here is my CustomDialogFragment code:

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_login.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import org.greenstand.android.TreeTracker.R
import org.greenstand.android.TreeTracker.application.Permissions
import org.greenstand.android.TreeTracker.utilities.*
import org.greenstand.android.TreeTracker.viewmodels.LoginViewModel
import org.koin.android.viewmodel.ext.android.viewModel
import timber.log.Timber
class CustomDialogFragment : DialogFragment()
{
    private var content: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        content = arguments!!.getString("content")

        val style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME
        val theme = R.style.DialogTheme
        setStyle(style, theme)
    }


    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup, savedInstanceState: Bundle): View
    {
        val view = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog, container, false)

        val btnAccept = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.buttonAccept) as Button

        val textViewContent = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.textViewContent) as TextView
        textViewContent.text = content;

        btnAccept.setOnClickListener{
            dismiss();
        }

        return view;
    }

    companion object
    {
        fun newInstance(content: String) : CustomDialogFragment
        {
            val f = CustomDialogFragment()

            val args = Bundle()
            args.putString("content", content)
            f.arguments = args

            return f
        }
    }

}
```

Can someone indicate what exactly I need to pass into the show method? Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Please post error message log. From first glance your code seems correct.

Comment: well, the only error I'm getting is from the actual show method itself

Comment: i'll edit my post

Comment: What are your `import` statements for `DialogFragment` and `FragmentManager`?

Comment: You're probably mixing support and framework fragments. Use only fragments and dialog fragments from the support library, not from the framework.

Comment: i'm very new to kotlin, so i'll post my imports

Comment: I do not see where you are importing `DialogFragment`.

Comment: well I'm not calling dialogfragment because I have my own DialogFragment implementation in my seperate class

Comment: I have edited my answer please take a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[UPDATE]
The problem is the method can receive a `FragmentManager` but it has to be not null, take a look at the error and the not nullable Kotlin symbol

`FragmentManager!!`

So you can do

```
fm?.let {newFragment.show(fm, "your tag")}
//fm here can also be it
```

Please see the comments in the Noushad Hasan answer

You are passing the `FragmentManager` to the method, it needs the `FragmentTransaction` and a `String` as a tag:

```
val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
newFragment.show(transaction, "SOME_TAG")
```

A couple of suggestions:

You can make you `DialogFragment` more *kotliny* by using the Kotlin standard functions

```
companion object {

        private const val KEY = "param1"

        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String) =
            ExampleDialogFragment().apply {
                arguments = bundleOf(KEY to param1)
            }
    }
```

You can get a good example by creating a `Fragment` using the Android Studio wizard and checking the factory method option.

Also, since the tag is gonna be for your `DialogFragment` you could make it a public constant:

```
 companion object {
        const val TAG = "TAG"
 }
```

And maybe you want to double check if the dialog fragment is already present and remove it, to actually work as a fresh dialog

```
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        val previous = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(ExampleDialogFragment.TAG)
        if (previous != null) {
            transaction.remove(previous)
        }
        transaction.addToBackStack(null)

        val dialogFragment = ExampleDialogFragment.newInstance("parameter")
        dialogFragment.show(transaction, ExampleDialogFragment.TAG)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your activity is a child of https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentActivity.html, for example you can use https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity as a parent activity.

Then to get the fragmentManager use the `getSupportFragment()` method, or just `val fm = supportFragmentManager`

Comment: my activity already extends AppCompatActivity, but calling supportFragmentManager in the show method gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

I see no `DialogFragment` imports in your `customDialog()` class. Actually, there is a Fragment import on `line no: 9`. are you sure you are extending from the correct `DialogFragment`?

Comment: `class CustomDialogFragment : DialogFragment()` ?

Comment: @cutiko I guess there should be a `androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment` import in his imports section. usually, this kind of error is caused because of mixing imports.

Comment: No, the error is because the show method needs the fragment transaction, not the fragment manager.

Comment: I see that but usually, that should not be the case with `DialogFragment` there are 2 show methods one that accepts a `fragment manager` & the other one that accepts a `fragment transaction`. if done right he should be able to use both of them.

Comment: You are rigth! Had to check the docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment Then the problem is other `FragmentManager!` notices the not null kotlin symbol

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
val newFragment = CustomDialogFragment()
newFragment.show(childFragmentMangar, "look")`
```